# Find the possible number of all real roots of $Q(x)=x^{2022}-x^{2020}+x^{2018}-x^{1011}+x^{1009}+s$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $s$ be a real number greater than $\frac {1}{4}$. Find the possible number of all real roots of  $$Q(x)=x^{2022}-x^{2020}+x^{2018}-x^{1011}+x^{1009}+s$$

---

I tried to simplify the polynomial but failed. For example,

$$Q(x)=x^{1009}(x^{1013}-x^{1011}+x^{1009}-x^2+1)+s$$ or $$Q(x)=x^{2020}(x^2-1)+x^{1009}(x^{1009}-x^2+1)+s$$

I don't have a good idea how to proceed.

Source: 9th grade competition problem .

Comment: If it was $2x^{2020}$ it would be quite easy.  Are you *absolutely* sure you have copied the question correctly?

Comment: @David Yes, the question is as written.

Comment: @David You can share your solution even for $2x^{2020}$ . I will appreciate.

Comment: If it's $2x^{2020}$ instead of $x^{2020}$: let $R=x^{1011}-x^{1009}$.  Then $Q=0$ implies $R^2-R+s=0$, and with $s>\frac14$ this has no real solutions.

Comment: @David Your method can be applied here: the only missing step is $Q(x) \geq Q(x) - x^{2020}$.  Your argument shows $Q(x) - x^{2020} > 0$ for all $x$ (without some of the details I had to worry about)

Comment: @David In essence, your insight allows you to write $$Q(x) = x^{2020} + \left(x^{1011}-x^{1009}-\frac12\right)^2 + (s-1/4)$$ (which may very well be the intended solution)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if this is the intended solution, but it works:

Suppose $x=c$ is a real root of
$$Q(x) = x^{2018}(x^4 - x^2 + 1) - x^{1009}(x^2-1) + s$$

Then in particular, $x=c$ is a root of the real polynomial
$$P(x) = x^{2018}(c^4-c^2+1) - x^{1009}(c^2-1) + s$$
which is quadratic in $x^{1009}$, and since it had a real root, it has a non-negative discriminant:
$$(c^2-1)^2-4s(c^4-c^2+1) \geq 0.$$

Now, note that $c^4-c^2+1 > 0$ [show this if you need to] and $s > \frac14$, so
$$(c^2-1)^2 \geq 4s(c^4-c^2+1) > c^4-c^2+1$$

Finally, solving this gives $c^2 < 0$, which is a contradiction.

Therefore there are no real roots of $Q$.

---

*Much more concise method*: Note that
$$Q(x) = \left(x^{1010}\right)^2 + \left(x^{1011}-x^{1009}-\frac12\right)^2 + \left(s - \frac14\right)$$
When $x$ is real, the first two terms are $\geq 0$ and the last term is $> 0$ by assumption, so $Q$ has no real zeros.